# Hierarchical clustering on sparse observation matrix

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to perform hierarchical clustering on large sparse observation matrix. The matrix represents movie ratings for a number of users.
My goal is to cluster similar users based on their movie preferences. However, I need a dendrogram, rather than single division. In order to do this, I tried to use *SciPy*:

```
R = dok_matrix((nrows, ncols), dtype=np.float32)

for user in ratings:
    for item in ratings[user]:
        R[item, user] = ratings[user][item]

Z = hierarchy.linkage(R.transpose().toarray(), method='ward')
```

This works fine on a small data-set:

[image]

However, I (obviously) get memory problems when scaling up.
If there any way I can feed **sparse** matrix to the algorithm?

Comment: Which package are you using for the clustering?   It's that code and its documentation that will tell whether it can work with sparse matrices or not.  Some `scikit-learn` functions work with sparse, but not all.

Comment: As I said, I use SciPy. Documentation of the method does not say anything about sparse matrices. Scikit does not allow producing dendrograms in a simple fashion (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Are you using a 1d compressed distance matrix?

Comment: No, I use observation matrix, not distance.

Comment: Scipy's hierarchical.linkage also accepts 1d compressed distance matrices.

Comment: I'm aware, but this is a different kind of problem. I don't have distance information, only (samples x features) matrix.

Comment: OK, the `scipy.cluster` package.

Comment: If you look at hierarchy.linkage's source code, you will see that it applies scipy.spatial.distance.pdist to your observational data, which returns a condensed distance matrix. I assume you are getting memory problems when computing the distance matrix, right?

Comment: It raises "ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.", not allowing me to pass anything else then ndarray.

Comment: try a ndarray of shape (N, 1).

Comment: If I put all data in a vector, how I can tell when one sample ends and another begins?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

Answer (score 1):

From `scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py` `linkage` processes the `y` argument as:

```
y = _convert_to_double(np.asarray(y, order='c'))

if y.ndim == 1:
    distance.is_valid_y(y, throw=True, name='y')
    [y] = _copy_arrays_if_base_present([y])
elif y.ndim == 2:
    if method in _EUCLIDEAN_METHODS and metric != 'euclidean':
        raise ValueError("Method '{0}' requires the distance metric "
                         "to be Euclidean".format(method))
    y = distance.pdist(y, metric)
else:
    raise ValueError("`y` must be 1 or 2 dimensional.")
```

When I apply `asarray` to a `dok` I get a 0d object array.  It just wraps the dictionary in an array.

```
In [905]: M=sparse.dok_matrix([[1,0,0,2,3],[0,0,0,0,1]])
In [906]: M
Out[906]: 
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
In [908]: m = np.asarray(M)
In [909]: m
Out[909]: 
array(<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>, dtype=object)
In [910]: m.shape
Out[910]: ()
```

`linkage` accepts a 1d compressed style distance matrix, or the equivalent 2d one.

Looking further in `linkage` I deduce that `ward` uses `nn_chain`, which is in the compiled `scipy/cluster/_hierarchy.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so` file.  That puts the working part of the method even further out of reach of the casual Python programmer.

Comment: Well, too bad. Thanks for the help. I guess I will have to switch to something else.

Comment: I wonder if the compressed sparse graph package has anything of use, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/sparse.csgraph.html

Comment: Any progress on this? My current solution is iterating through individual vectors in parallel.