# Is there any way to perform hierarchical clustering on sparse data with distance matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a (60000, 60000) sparse matrix of cosine distances? Are there any frameworks or in-built scipy instruments to perform a hierarchical clustering on that data?
In [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660848/hierarchical-clustering-on-sparse-observation-matrix) author has observation matrix rather than distance.

Comment: Is this useful? http://dev.bizo.com/2012/01/clustering-of-sparse-data-using-python.html

Comment: If your distance matrix is sparse that means most of your observations are a distance of 0 from each other. I'm not sure hierarchical clustering makes sense for your data.

Comment: @MaxPierini unfortunately not very, I am looking for hierarchical clustering, and sklearn does not support one for sparse matrixes

Comment: @CJR Not necessary, sparse format works when most of observations are similar. It is usually zeros, but not in my case

Comment: Please, add the code to reproduce a sample of your matrix

Comment: While true, scipy sparse matrices define unstored values as 0 by convention. I don't think there's an easy way around that for clustering.